# Setting the bar of a CTabCtrl to transparent

Tags: mfc, ctabctrl

I have a `CTabCtrl` and I am using **WindowsBlinds** to skin my computer GUI.

[image: Tab Control]

This is a **MFC** `CDialog` object.

Is there anything I can do in code so that the grey area renders transparent?

I tried setting the transparent resource property but it did not work.

Comment: What if u delete background with OnEraseBackground() function

Comment: I am not sure that this works without using custom draw / ownerdraw. The function DrawThemeParentBackground will help you in a themed enviroment.

Comment: @xMRi Thanks to you both. I was hoping there was a simple solution for this. I don't think it is worth creating a new control for such a cosmetic adjustment. Thanks all the same.

Comment: Side note: There is no reason at this moment to use a `CTabCtrl`. A `CMFCTabCtrl` is far superior.

Comment: @sergiol Interesting. In my case though I on need the tab buttons. Under that is just the same tree control. Is it worth changing over for that?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: It is. With `CTabCtrl` you have to manage manually visibility and enabled/disabled state of controls at the moment user switches among each tab. In `CFMCTabCtrl` you don't have to do anything manually; you only have to pass to `AddTab` a pointer to the control which will be the background of the tab, which can be anything cast'able to `CWnd*`

Comment: @sergiol in my case it would be the same tree control. But it is already on the dialog resource. I only change what the control shows based on tab clicked. The tree event handlers are the same for both ways of showing data.